# Sample from a skewed distribution in R

Tags: r, random, distribution

I want to sample numbers from a skewed distribution in R. Let's say I want to sample numbers from a distribution with mode `10` and 95% of values between `5` and `20`.

Is there a function in `R`, similar to `rnorm()` or `runif()` that can generate random numbers from such a distribution?

Comment: Well, there is a number of skewed distributions. The log-normal comes to mind: `help("dlnorm")`. However, many of them only have two parameters. It's unlikely that you can find one with exactly that mode and quantiles unless they have been calculated for this distribution.

Comment: If you want to set a mode, you have to work with a discrete data which you can create like 10 times 1, 9 times 2 etc. or you have to set a bin size for a continuous data.

Comment: In a continuous data set like `rnorm(), runif()` etc, the mode is 1/inf which is zero since it is continuous. To be able to set a mode, you should have a discrete random data set, or if you desire to work with a continuous one, you should separate your data into bins as like the histogram does. So, mode=10 should come with a determined bin size.

Comment: @maydin ["A mode of a continuous probability distribution is often considered to be any value x at which its probability density function has a locally maximum value, so any peak is a mode."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics))

Comment: @maydin I don't follow. OP is referring to the mode of a distribution of a random variable. Data points don't play into that.

Comment: @Roland Yes. yes. I just realized, and deleted my last command. I repeat, I haven't heard that definition before, and it makes the things easier then if it is the case... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choosing a [log normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) with `μ = 2.415195` and `σ = 0.3355733` will give a distrubution with (approximately) your requirements.

```
mu <- 2.415195
sigma <- 0.3355733

N <- 10000000
nums <- rlnorm(N, mu, sigma)
```

Approximately `95%` of values are between `5` and `20`.

```
sum(5 < nums & nums < 20) / N
#> [1] 0.9500141
```

Mode is `10`

```
ggplot(tibble(x = nums), aes(x)) +
  geom_density() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 10, color = "red") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(5, 20), color = "blue")
```

[image: distribution]

---

I got these parameters using `optimize`.

From any `σ`, we can calculate what `μ` gives us a mode of `10` because the mode is: [image: mode]

So we want to find what `σ` gets us closest to 95% of values between `5` and `20`. This can be calculated from the difference between `cdf(20)` and `cdf(5)`. The CDF for the log normal distribution is: [image: cdf]. (`plnorm` in R).

```
f <- function(sigma) {
  mu <- log(10) + sigma^2
  
  abs(plnorm(20, mu, sigma) - plnorm(5, mu, sigma) - 0.95)
}

optimize(f, lower = 0, upper = 1)
#> $minimum
#> [1] 0.3355733
#> 
#> $objective
#> [1] 1.160349e-05
```

Comment: You should always use the CDF as implemented in R: `plnorm` (alternatively, you could use its inverse `qlnorm`). I'd expected it to deal better with edge cases and values for out on the tail.

Comment: Thanks, Roland. I've updated my answer to use `plnorm`.